# Access denied for user from a remote host

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to connect with MySQL Database, but I'm getting *"Access denied from user 'remoteuser'@'cmapc.iserver.local'"*. Let me show you all the scenario:

I have a server **Ubuntu 14.04** with hostname 'icmaserver', **MySQL 5.6** and **Bind9** to configure a local DNS Server. The server points to itself domain 'iserver.local' and each machine has a subdomain configured at Bind9 DNS: *[machine-name].iserver.local* which in the networking connections receives the DNS sufix as 'iserver.local' and it points the primary DNS to my local server.

At this point, is everything working well, all machines are communicating to each other and all services such as: FTP, SSH, are working well. The firewall is configurated to enable all necessary ports. But, there's a problem.

I can't connect to MySQL from any machine (with host [machine-name].iserver.local or with local IP). I always getting *"Access denied from user 'remoteuser'@'[machine-name].iserver.local'"*.

I've tried:

```
CREATE USER 'remoteuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '**********';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'remoteuser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

It not worked, so I've tried:

```
CREATE USER 'remoteuser'@'%.iserver.local' IDENTIFIED BY '**********';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'remoteuser'@'%.iserver.local' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

It not worked, so I've tried:

```
CREATE USER 'remoteuser'@'cmapc.iserver.local' IDENTIFIED BY '**********';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'remoteuser'@'cmapc.iserver.local' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

It not worked, so I've tried:

```
CREATE USER 'remoteuser'@'192.168.1.100' IDENTIFIED BY '**********';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'remoteuser'@'192.168.1.100' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

And I don't know what's going wrong...

**EDIT**

The file *my.cnf* has the line `# bind-address=127.0.0.1` commented.

**EDIT 2**

The problem with connection is in Windows 10 of a machine. I've tried to connect with another machine in the same network and also with Windows 10 (jeapc.iserver.local) and I got success! But when I tried, again, to connect with (cmapc.iserver.local) Windows 10 machine... I got *"Access denied from user 'remoteuser'@'cmapc.iserver.local'"*. I don't know how I can fix it in Windows...

Comment: How are you attempting to connect? Assuming cmapc.iserver.local is a linux host? Is your command `mysql -u remoteuser -p -h icmaserver.iserver.local`?

Comment: @Deathgrip I'm using a windows machine for cmapc.iserver.local and Ubuntu Server for icmaserver.iserver.local. I'm using HeidiSQL to try to connect to MySQL then I get "Access denied from user 'remoteuser'@'cmapc.iserver.local'".